# How to make @JsonIgnore working on generic class (List)?

Tags: java, jackson

Same `@JsonIgnore` applied to both String and List. It is working on String but not List. 
Jackson version 2.3.0. Below is the sample program to print out the output for setter properties. Setter properties still shown for testList property. 
The workaround might be `mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS);` but it is not my desired behaviour. I want to control on the object itself.

```
package my.com.myriadeas.ilmu.bootstrap;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBuilder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;

public class JsonFactoryTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws JsonMappingException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS);
        mapper.registerModule(new TestJacksonModule());
        JavaType javaType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().uncheckedSimpleType(
                TestJsonProperty.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.canDeserialize(javaType));
    }

    public static class TestJsonProperty {
        @JsonIgnore
        private String testString;
        @JsonProperty
        public String getTestString() {
            return testString;
        }
        @JsonIgnore
        public void setTestString(String testString) {
            this.testString = testString;
        }

        @JsonIgnore
        private List<String> testList;
        @JsonProperty
        public List<String> getTestList() {
            return testList;
        }
        @JsonIgnore
        public void setTestList(List<String> testList) {
            this.testList = testList;
        }
    }

    public static class TestJacksonModule extends SimpleModule {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8628204972239032380L;

        public TestJacksonModule() {
            setDeserializerModifier(new AssociationUriResolvingDeserializerModifier());
        }
    }

    private static class AssociationUriResolvingDeserializerModifier extends
            BeanDeserializerModifier {
        public AssociationUriResolvingDeserializerModifier() {

        }

        @Override
        public BeanDeserializerBuilder updateBuilder(
                DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc,
                BeanDeserializerBuilder builder) {
            Iterator<SettableBeanProperty> properties = builder.getProperties();
            while (properties.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("deserialize property= " + properties.next());
            }
            return builder;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to make sure: what exactly are you trying to do? Since you use both `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty`, what should happen is that "setter" and field are ignored; but "getter" should still be used. Is this not how code works now?

Comment: This works fine for primitive type but not collection. Same `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty` annotation on String and Collection but different output. You can run the program and see the output.

Comment: No, I meant what is it _supposed_ to do, what is the goal. I can see what it does, but I can't say what the intent here is, what are you trying to achieve. Saying something doesn't work won't help if definition of working is not clear.

Comment: How to make String and Collection behave the same instead of the globally to disable the feature? This is what I want

Comment: You are just repeating the same vague statement. But ok: I am guessing what you mean is that somehow value of `List` property would be set via `get` method? FWIW, you can alternatively change visibility on class using `@JsonAutoDetect` to prevent use of getter, if you still want ability to use "getter-as-setter" (although unless you really need it, I'd disable it altogether).

Comment: Thanks for alternative way. I will try it. Please try to run the program. You will set setter is there for testList but not testString. Both having exactly same annotation. Why it is behave that way? I can make both behave the same way by using `mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS)` but why is it  like that?